# Detecting scrolling with a Magic Mouse using a CFCallback

Tags: macos, mouse, iokit, magic-mouse

Can I find out how much a Magic Mouse has scrolled by in a `IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback` function?

I am trying to detect the scrolling gesture from a Magic Mouse using the CFCallbacks. I have it working fine with a standard USB mouse with a scroll wheel, but it seems that the Magic Mouse reports scrolling in a different way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the scroll information from the window event in Cocoa instead. Not a full fix for this issue but I still was able to access the scroll message.